# Ranking system algorithm help

Tags: algorithms

I’m currently in need of help for developing an algorithm for a dynamic ranking system.
I’m working on developing a children’s site where it will feature Ranking Chart on the website.

Here is the problem I’m having:
On each page, there will be 3 buttons that the users can press: Smiley Face, Love Heart, and a Gift Box.

The overall score of each page will be contribute to its’ ranking. 
Its’ ranking is determined by the amount of Smiley Faces, Love Hearts and Gift Boxes they receive. We want smiley faces to be worth more (75%), Love Hearts (20%), Gift Boxes (5%).

I’d like the ranking to change every hour, but it will keep into account how it ranked in previous hours, so it slowly tapers off the Ranking Charts rather than having it suddenly jolt out of the chart position, or a sudden rise up the chart.
The overall idea is to keep the Chart current and dynamic based on what’s popular at the moment.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: _We want smiley faces to be worth more (75%), Love Hearts (25%), Gift Boxes (5%)._ Total 105%?

Comment: Oops, my apologies I meant 100%. Fixed original post.